How to uninstall Ubuntu partition without affecting system
I have tried to remove it directly by deleting the Ubuntu partition volume but unfortunately PCs get stacks and unable to boot again.

Assuming you have a dual-boot system, firstly ensure the OS you'll keep owns the boot process; then you can safely erase/delete the unwanted partition(s). If you remove the partition(s) without ensuring the OS you'll keep owns the boot process, you can end up with an unbootable system (if the OS that controls the boot process is deleted; you'll need recovery media for your wanted OS in that case)

Your question is unclear.  You can't "uninstall" a partition without affecting the system.  Maybe you mean without affecting the rest of the system.  In which case, it would help to know what part of the system you want unaffected.

Example...  My current box has 7 partitions on its SSD; I know one OS controls boot (one always does) and that OS requires two partitions to operate so those two partitions cannot be safely deleting without impacting the systems boot; but the other five partitions I can safely delete without impacting boot. If I wanted to delete the Ubuntu systems I'm currently using (that controls boot), I'd have to boot into another OS (another release of Ubuntu) and have it take over control of boot process; then I could safely delete the / partition of my currently running OS; both use same ESP

This question is similar to: Removing an Ubuntu installation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
